# how can i get the function to return me an object with categories?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nested

So, im trying to classify objects of food category or tech category, as an object by categories as a final result. I have this input for the arguments in my function and then my end result should return me an object with both

```
{
 tech:  [ { tech product }, { tech product } ],
 food:  [ { food product }, { food product } ],
}
```

So what i have is a function where i try to construct an array with objects classifying the products. So far this is what i have been able to develop is this code, but for some reason I only get it to return me an empty object, not an object with both categories as I'm trying to.

```
function sortProducts (matrix) {
  const matrixResult = {};
  for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    let techProd = matrix[i];
    let techCategory = matrix[i].category;
    let techCategFilter = techCategory === ‘tech’;
    if (techCategFilter){
      let arrTech = []
      arrTech.push (techProd[i]);
      matrixResult.tech = arrTech;
    }
  }
   for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    let foodProd = matrix[i];
    let foodCategory = matrix[i].category;
    let foodCategFilter = foodCategory === ‘food’;
    if (foodCategFilter){
      let arrFood = []
      arrFood.push (foodProd[i]);
      matrixResult.food = arrFood;
    }
  }
  return matrixResult;
}
```

What am i missing or where am i messing up?

Comment: i see multiple issues with this code. 1=> `arrFood` and `arrTech` arrays are initialized every time in loop so older objects pushed are getting overwritten every time in the if block and you will have only 1 object max always. 2=> `foodProd = matrix[i]` will give you the food product object but then you push `foodProd[i]` to array which i guess will be undefined.

Comment: if you need something like group by category, use reducer function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#grouping_objects_by_a_property

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce or filter, depending on how big your array is.
I decided on forEach, since it is easier to read.

```
const result = {};

products.forEach(product => {
  const category = product.category;
  if (result[category]) {
    result[category].push(product);
  } else {
    result[category] = [product];
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues with this code.

1. `arrFood` and `arrTech` arrays are initialized every time in loop so older objects pushed are getting overwritten every time in the if block and you will have only 1 object max always.
2. `foodProd = matrix[i]` will give you the food product object but then you push `foodProd[i]` to array which i guess will be undefined.

Try this (fixed the above issues and also shorten little bit):

```
function sortProducts (matrix) {
  const matrixResult = { tech: [], food: []};

  for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    let techProd = matrix[i];
    if (techProd.category === 'tech'){
      matrixResult.tech.push (techProd);
    }
  }
   for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    let foodProd = matrix[i];
    if (foodProd.category === 'food'){
      matrixResult.food.push (foodProd);
    }
  }
  return matrixResult;
}
```

you can as well use forEach instead of looping or reducer as suggested by @HPSingh.

forEach example:

```
var matrixResult = { tech: [], food: []};
matrix.forEach( obj => {
  if(obj.category === 'food') matrixResult.food.push(obj);
  else if(obj.category === 'tech') matrixResult.tech.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: this can be achieved in single-loop.

Comment: @HPSingh correct. i added forEach example as well.

Answer (score 0):

So after checking with a colleague he recommended this which worked very well

```
function sortProducts (matrix) {
  const tech = [];
  const food = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    const arr = matrix[i];

    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      const product = arr[j];
      
      if ( product.category === 'tech') {
        tech.push(product);
      } else if (product.category === 'food') {
        food.push(product);
      }
    };
  };  
  
  return {
    tech: tech,
    food: food,
  }
}
```